# How many connections on a Single Port

Tags: c#, sockets, gps

I've developed an application for Tracking vehicles via GPS. So, all vehicles which have the GPS module fit, will send data to my server.

My Windows Server 2008 R2 has port 9900 assigned for incoming data.

If I have say 1000 vehicles in future, which all send data(via TCP) may be at same time to server(all connecting on the same port).

Then will single port work?

Also, if some one can refer me to a free test tools by which I can simulate the GPS traffic.

Comment: Yes it will work...... but if the load increases then I think you need  some more reading on how to balance the load, how huge traffic is handled o ports and so many other aspects come......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fb7a6ef7-5a70-43a4-b0fe-c0252877467b/concurrent-tcp-connection?forum=winservergen) topic, i think it will help.

From another side, connection management in practice depends on how your client\server application is done:

1. "notification" - client just send data to server (less then 1Kb)
2. "short session" - client connects to the server and do some data exchange
3. "long session" - client connects to the server and do permanent data exchange

So in the first case, you can just open the port listen connections, and close connection when data recieved.

In the third case connection procedure should be complex:

1. server has few listen ports - one for connection management, others for data exchange
2. client connects to the default port (connection management)
3. server selects data exchange port that has less number of connections, and says to   client to connect to this port for data exchange
4. client disconnects from connection management port and connects to allocated data exchange port

In the second case you should decide what scenario should you use (depends on number of clients, and length of data sessions).

Comment: We have the second case. Short session of 1-5 seconds with data less than 1KB. Actually the device makes a connection, sends data and waits for the server to disconnect. Now if the server wants to send any controlling command to the device. It can send and then disconnect, in case of now command the server immediately disconnects the client after data is received. Is that optimized and can it handle at least 500 devices with each device sending data in interval of 30 seconds.

Comment: Dynamic data ports can play havok with NAT configuration. This is demonstrated nicely with FTP. Avoid it is possible. Iportantly, a listener can accept a connection and redirect to a new socket _without requiring a new handshake_.

Comment: @Ashish Charan in your case i think you can manage it on single port. But cettainly it would be better to do some tests, for ex. to write simple client, emulating the device, then you can run plenty number of them for server stress testing.